# Is there a way to receive a notification as soon as a certain task with a certain task id is successful or fails using Celery for Python?

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task

I want to know if there is a way to monitor whether or not a task completes or fails as soon as it does using python celery. I have an event I want to fire up based on the results of a certain task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your task as a celery `@shared_task` with a `try except` block inside:

```
@shared_task
def my_task(input1, input2, ...):
    Setting up...
    try:
        Do stuff
        fire_success_event() <- Your success event
    except Exception:
        The above stuff failed
        fire_fail_event() <- your fail event
        return 1 <- fail
    return 0 <- success
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks but I would want to know whether the task `my_task` has Succeeded or Failed. More precisely, I want to receive a notification kind of like having a listener that is just waiting for the task to succeed or fail, then act accordingly.

Comment: Then instead of the events, use a return statement (typically 0: success, 1:fail). I will edit my answer

Comment: When I do that I seem to keep getting a fail since the task might be pending at the point I check what it returns. Check back to my earlier comment

Comment: That is why I was initially suggesting to fire your events from within the celery task!

Comment: Good to know mate :)