# Execute a callback upon task end?

Tags: python, celery

Celery. An app sends a task to be executed.

```
r = task.delay()
```

Is it possible to execute code *in the app address space* upon task end other than by polling `r`?

Comment: This may be possible in Celery 5 as they are going to work on improvements in async handling...

Comment: Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: Look for Celery 5 tags on GitHub as well as celery-5 tagged issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way in celery.  Generally speaking, you will have to come up with your own way for the task to send a notification back to your app if you want to perform the callback processing in the calling application's address space.

Here are some patterns you can use:

- [The general pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273898/is-there-a-way-to-receive-a-notification-as-soon-as-a-certain-task-with-a-certai)
- [Using django channels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000392/6043170)
- [Using firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50800680/6043170)